# Credentials in GoogleCalendar API with service account (Java)

Tags: google-calendar-api, service-accounts, google-api-java-client

Right now I need to implement an app to create some google-calendar events but for a service account. I saw examples in docs that create events using `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp` (or similar) to create a `Credential` instance (com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential) but it works for regular user accounts and not for Service account (I already have the JSON file with key info from my ServiceAccount).
Next lines show what's the ideal for me (of course is not working because  Calendar.Builder needs some `Credential` obj as a third param)

```
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
        .createScoped(Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));
    Calendar calendar = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
```

How I can get a `Credential` obj using/from a .JSON key file (service account) to use with `Calendar.Builder`? or maybe I'm missing something else and/or there is another way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sample should get you started make sure to set the UserEmail to the email address of the user on  your Workspace domain that you want to delegate to.

One of these should work.

version 1:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
    .fromStream(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
    .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
    .createScoped(CalendarScopes.all());
```

Version 2:

```
private GoogleCredential authorize1() {

    GoogleCredential credential = null;

    HttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    try {

      InputStream jsonFileStream =
          DriveSample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json");

      GoogleCredential readJsonFile = GoogleCredential
          .fromStream(jsonFileStream, httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY).createScoped(DriveScopes.all());

      credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(readJsonFile.getTransport())
          .setJsonFactory(readJsonFile.getJsonFactory())
          .setServiceAccountId(readJsonFile.getServiceAccountId())
          .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
          .setServiceAccountScopes(readJsonFile.getServiceAccountScopes())
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(readJsonFile.getServiceAccountPrivateKey()).build();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return credential;
}
```

here is a link on how to set up delegation. Just make sure to swap out the scope for the google calendar scope.

- [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.cn/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation?hl=fa)

Comment: Great, thanks @DalmTo. I'll try those. Just in case... is always needed to give "Domain-wide deletation of authority" to my service account? (In my case I just need to update a calendar already created and assigned/shared with this service account)

Comment: It has to be a calendar on your domain.  Sharing calendars with service accounts doesn't work anymore as far as i know.  Thats why we need to use delegation.

Comment: Cool, its on same domain. I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot say it is working but I have two conflicts that i'm working to solve:
1- "GoogleCredential" and others are deprecated (looking for alternatives)
2- Some dependencies issues on my end. 
Thanks @DalmTo anyway!